# Google Sheets - Duplicate Tabs Automatically with Numbered Names

Tags: google-sheets

We are currently building a KPI file for our sales team. I currently have a Google Sheets file with a Monthly tab and one tab for each day of the month (1, 2, 3, 4) and so on. I would like to make a script that allows me to duplicate Tab Day 1 into 30 more tabs that are auto-numbered. In the end, I should have a Monthly tab and a tab for each day of the month which were all duplicated from tab Day 1 and named accordingly.

Comment: All right. What have you written so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice addon I use for that type of thing. it was developed by Alice Keeler for teachers to create a set of tabs from a roster, naming each tab from the roster page.  she made two versions.. i highly recommend looking through her list of templates/addons, as she has a lot of them that do things i was unaware were possible in sheets

Rostertabs 
Simply makes a blank sheet for each entry in the roster.  doesn't have to be names... whatever you put in each line under the 'names' header will be the name on the generated tabs.

TemplateTabs
Exactly as above, but rather than the blank tab as above, you instead have a second input tab for the template, and when you generate the tabs it will copy and rename the template for each item in the name list.

Her Website:
https://alicekeeler.com/

The specific sheets:
Clicking the link will automatically prompt you to save a blank copy to your google drive, which you can then adjust to your needs.

Rostertabs
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YgG-uniVbTHt43ENFrFJQwKG7BxxoM2f-JmriuvKkpw/copy

templatetabs
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fMke8r7Ww5uJg_Q5EjtNtQpHJtEuurK34hoox3avQ00/copy